# Observe/Listen for changes in REST API response

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

I am building an API where I want to observe another 3rd party API that tells me the current "status" of a user. I want to do something (run a code-block) when the status of the user changes.

For example, the 3rd API tells me if the user is "Happy", "Sad" at that point in time.
I want to do something when the User's status changes from "Happy" to "Sad".
So is there a way to know when this change is happening (And do some action at that point)?

One potential solution I found is to run a Cron Job, where I continuously call the 3rd party API and keep checking the status of the user and do something when it changes.

I am looking for any other potential solutions which can do the same with a better approach.
If you want to go tech-stack specific, I am building my API in Node(Express).

Comment: Does the 3rd Party API contact you, or do you need to poll it constantly to get the information? Is it a REST-API? Nevertheless save every "mood" in a database and check the db-record on every push/poll. Since the other API is outside of your system scope, there is no way of a real 'subscriptions'.

Comment: It is a REST-API. I just want to detect the change of value. I am trying to avoid such a situation you mentioned as it is really inefficient. I am looking for a better approach. I am new to the backend, so I was wondering if I missed something which is a more efficient approach.